# Exclude a control from update panel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have placed a 3rd party control inside update panel after doing asynchronous postback of page associated js file of that control is not working. Is there any method to exclude a control from updatepanel. ie i don't want to post that control.

Comment: Does that control use javascript? Is it possible to reduce the content of that update panel?

Comment: Explude from UpdatePanel? Remove it! I would recommend to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to split up your updatepanel into 2 or more, leaving your 3rd party component outside that panels.
Is it possible in your situation?
If you post your page's code, I could be more precise...

Answer (score 1):

I found the exact answer for this at http://forums.asp.net/t/1098549.aspx.  I'm reproducing it here with only slight modification:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
...Other controls...
<!-- This is the control to exclude -->
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkExport" runat="server" OnClick="lnkExport_Click" Text="Export Data"></asp:LinkButton>

    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
          <!-- There are two types of triggers, AsyncPostBackTriggerand plain
               PostBackTrigger.
               Be sure to use PostBackTrigger here, which will cause a complete
               postback by this control. -->
          <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="lnkExport" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My particular problem was I had a chart control in an update panel, with a button that would allow the user to download the image of the chart.  If that button was triggering the update panel, the download didn't work.  But specifying the trigger as `PostBackTrigger` (as opposed to `AsyncPostBackTrigger` did the trick.